# PDO query returns no result when querying the mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite, pdo

Im developing an Android app which uses mysql database to store information. When I have the following function in my php code:

```
/*
 * Get User details
 * 
 */
public function getUserDetailsEse($email)
{
   $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("
SELECT u.title
     , u.name
     , u.surname
     , s.reg_num
     , s.barcode
     , s.prog
     , s.yos
     , s.sem
     , s.nat_id
     , s.dob
     , s.mobile
     , s.email
     , s.addr
     , s.registad_courses 
  FROM `users` u
     , `students` s 
 WHERE u.id=s.uza_id 
   AND s.email= ?
");

$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        // user existed 
        echo 'Query ran but nun';
        $stmt->close();
        return true;
    } else {
        // user not existed
        echo 'Query ddnt run';
        $stmt->close();
        return false;
    }

$stmt->close();
}
```

In which I want to fetch those details from the mysql database,then display them in my sqlite database to be used inside the app. I then call the function using:

```
$details = $db->getUserDetailsEse($email);

if ($details!=FALSE){
    $response1["error"] = FALSE;
    $response1["id"] = $details["id"];
    $response1["details"]["title"] = $details["title"];
    $response1["details"]["name"] = $details["name"];
    $response1["details"]["surname"] = $details["surname"];
    $response1["details"]["reg_num"] = $details["reg_num"];
    $response1["details"]["barcode"] = $details["barcode"];
    $response1["details"]["prog"] = $details["prog"];
    $response1["details"]["yos"] = $details["yos"];
    $response1["details"]["sem"] = $details["sem"];
    $response1["details"]["nat_id"] = $details["nat_id"];
    $response1["details"]["dob"] = $details["dob"];
    $response1["details"]["mobile"] = $details["mobile"];
    $response1["details"]["email"] = $details["email"];
    $response1["details"]["addr"] = $details["addr"];
    $response1["details"]["registad_courses"] = $details["registad_courses"];
    echo json_encode($response1);
}  else {
    $response1["error"] = TRUE;
    $response1["error_msg"] = "Failed to fetch details. Login credentials are wrong. Please try again!";
    echo json_encode($response1);
}
```

When i run the query in phpmyadmin it works fine:
[image]

But when i try to run it on Postman, i get the following error:
[image]

Here are the 2 table I'm querying:
[image]

[image]

EDIT:TRYING TO PRINT $DETAILS
[image]

Comment: Did you try printing $details = $db->getUserDetailsEse($email);print_r($details); ?

Comment: @Poria I just tried, I have added the result screenshot in the edit of the question

Answer (score 1):

As you can see on postman response, Login credentials are wrong.
Did you configure your connection on PDO ?

If your are using PDO, look below for the connection.

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
?>
```

EDIT:
On my env i tried this

```
    public function getUserDetailsEse($email)
{
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("
  SELECT u.title
 , u.name
 , u.surname
 , s.reg_num
 , s.barcode
 , s.prog
 , s.yos
 , s.sem
 , s.nat_id
 , s.dob
 , s.mobile
 , s.email
 , s.addr
 , s.registad_courses 
 FROM `users` u
 , `students` s 
WHERE u.id=s.uza_id AND u.email = :email
");

    $stmt->bindParam("email", $email);

    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        // user existed
        echo 'Query ran but nun';
        $stmt->closeCursor();
        return true;
    } else {
        // user not existed
        echo 'Query ddnt run';
        $stmt->closeCursor();
        return false;
    }

    $stmt->closeCursor();
}
```

If this still doesn't work, the point isn't into your query.

Comment: @Antony Matignon The connection is fine,Thats the error message I just used which says the credentials are wrong as you can read in the above code, If you read the second code snippet You'll see it

Comment: Oh yeah, i didn't saw it the first time. Well look at `$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("
SELECT u.title
     , u.name
     , u.surname
     , s.reg_num
     , s.barcode
     , s.prog
     , s.yos
     , s.sem
     , s.nat_id
     , s.dob
     , s.mobile
     , s.email
     , s.addr
     , s.registad_courses 
  FROM `users` u
     , `students` s 
 WHERE u.id=s.uza_id 
   AND s.email= ?
");` You have s.email = ?, if you replace the ? with :email and in your bind param switch s to email. Does it work ?

Comment: And if you try with `bindParam()` no underscore ?

Comment: It ddnt work as well, I actually copied what u wrote...but I split the queries into two separate queries and it worked, guess I'm going to stick with that for the moment....thanks a lot!!!